# Three.js Typeface.js offline

Tags: three.js, typeface

the problem is obvious from the title, http://typeface.neocracy.org offline. It was used to convert fonts and used in conjunction with THREE.TextGeometry. But if it is offline, how is now possible to use custom fonts in three.js?

Comment: [The code is here](https://code.launchpad.net/typeface.js). Looks like the converter is inside so you can run it locally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made a new converter that outputs the same files as typeface.js.

http://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/

Answer (score 1):

I loaded the source, but as far as I can see there is no chance to create the JS-font-files with this distribution. Maybe for someone with deep perl-knowledge...? In any case I installed perl, the ppm and dmake but trying to exec the Makefile only leads to errormessages about missing files. No - this is no alternative to the online-converter. Even worser: I didn't find any other converter or another side using the same one (cufon seems to create another format). So let's hope the site comes back to live - otherwise the great textfeature of three.js is worth nothing in the moment.